# Creating edge causes thread to hang

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph database with Members and Product SKUs.  I want to create a "seen" edge from a member to a collection of SKUs.

However, the create edge operation occasionally hangs, in both an API call to Node.createRelationshipTo and using a cypher query.

Also, I have tried creating a new dummy member from which to draw the edge, in the case that this is some kind of locking issue.

Here are various attempts I've made on this issue.

Using the java API:

```
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        Node memberNode = graphDb.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("Member"));
        // The following line is to use the same user.
        //Node memberNode = 
        //graphDb.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(DynamicLabel.label("Member"), "id",    
        //member_id).iterator().next();

        System.out.println("Marking sku as seen...");

        memberNode.createRelationshipTo(node, new RelationshipType() {
            @Override
            public String name() {
                return "seen";
            }
        });

        tx.success();
    }
```

Using Cypher:

```
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        Object skuId = node.getProperty("id");
        if (skuId instanceof Integer){
            Integer iSkuId = (Integer) skuId;
            skuId = new Long(iSkuId);
        }
        String cypher = "MATCH (s:SKU {id:{sku_id}}), (m:Member {id:{member_id}})\n" +
                "CREATE (m)-[:seen]->(s)\n";

        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap();
        params.put("member_id", member_id);
        params.put("sku_id", skuId);

        engine.execute(cypher, params);
        tx.success();
    }
```

I have also tried MERGE in the cypher instead of CREATE.

The behavior of this code is that I can run it several times and it'll be ok, but then occasionally "Marking SKU as seen..." will get written to the log and then nothing else (it hangs before drawing all the edges).

Additionally, when I stop my graph after this problem, I get log messages such as:

> 14:16:55.882 [Thread-32] WARN  o.e.j.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool -        qtp364159521{STOPPING,8<=1<=80,i=0,q=0} Couldn't stop Thread[qtp364159521-57,5,main]
>   2014-04-14 18:17:18.099+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
>   Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..

FIXED:

I needed to close my transactions with tx.close().

Many java samples have try-catches with a transaction like:

```
    try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx())
    {

        tx.success();
    }
```

This calls tx.close() for you.

However, if you're not using the most up-to-date java, you have to use the old style try-catch wherein you must call tx.close() explicitly.

Mad props to Andy Rosenbaum for solving this problem for me.